# Параллельный вызов асинхронных методов ASP.NET.CORE

Tags: asp.net-core, c#-7.0

Существует проблема. При фильтрации данных таблицы я определяю CompanyLocation, которая тянет данные с таблиц Region и Company. Но определение идёт только для одного параметра, либо regions либо companies.

```
     IndexViewModel viewModel = new IndexViewModel
        {

            CompanyLocations = await  companies.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync(),
            //CompanyLocations = await companies.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync(),

            FilterViewModel = new FilterViewModel(_context.Regions.ToList(), _context.Companies.ToList(), company, region),


        };
```

То есть я не могу вызвать оба параметра для фильтрации данных. Как сделать так, чтобы эти две операции выполнялись параллельно?
Вот код всего метода:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> CompanyLocationIndex(int? company, int? 
    region)
          {
        IQueryable<CompanyLocationModel> regions = _context.CompanyLocations.Include(x => x.Region);
        IQueryable<CompanyLocationModel> companies = _context.CompanyLocations.Include(x => x.Company);
          if (company != null && company != 0)
        {
            companies = companies.Where(p => p.Company.Id == company);
        }

        if (region != null && region != 0)
        {
            regions = regions.Where(p => p.Region.Id == region);
        }
            IndexViewModel viewModel = new IndexViewModel
        {

            CompanyLocations = await  companies.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync(),
            //CompanyLocations = await companies.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync(),

            FilterViewModel = new FilterViewModel(_context.Regions.ToList(), _context.Companies.ToList(), company, region),


        };

        return View(viewModel);

    }
}
```